# /etc/hosts file not redirecting to local application on mac

Tags: macos, hosts

I've set up a redirect in the hosts file on my machine that basically points an auth domain to my local project in IIS (when run in Visual Studio for Mac) - however when I type the domain name into Chrome (for example), I get a message saying this site cannot be reached.

The local URL I want this to point to is: http://localhost:44380/ - the live URL I can't reveal for security but lets say for the sake of this example that it's: auth.site.com (the actual URL I'm using is valid and it does load in Chrome)

Here's my hosts file from terminal as it's currently set up:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       auth.site.com
```

I'm very familiar with windows and how the hosts file works, so from what I know there this would work in windows (I think anyways), is there something I'm missing here because obviously something isn't right?

Comment: Is `auth.site.com` and `localhost` using same port numbers?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - although it is something I can check with the dev team

Comment: The `/etc/hosts` is only replacing the ip address, not the port number. So if you listen on the same port number (http:80,https:443) on `localhost` it might work.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be editing `/private/etc/hosts` on macOS? Are you sure your changes are being retained?

Comment: This could be because of HSTS as well. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security

If you opened the original server website on chrome, then it will remember that the site needs to be browser on HTTPS only

Answer (score 5):

I would first check where the problem is exactly. I think of the following possible issues:

1. Hosts file not properly working: Try running `ping auth.site.com` in a terminal. If you see responses from 127.0.0.1 this should work.
2. Is access to the port possible, open http://localhost:44380 in your browser. If you see your page, this should work.
3. Combine the two parts: open http://auth.site.com:44380 in your browser. If this does not work, maybe there are security features from the original page you visited before preventing access (like forcing SSL or a pinned certificate).
4. Try another browser or `curl auth.site.com:44380` in a terminal.

If you are not happy with the given ports, you can do a [port forwarding](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/what-is-the-modern-way-to-do-port-forwarding-on-el-capitan-forward-port-80-to). Changing ports is not possible in the hosts file, because the hosts file is only for domain name lookup and this has nothing to do with the ports.

Comment: I keep getting a webpage that says "It works!" which is not the page I was hoping for (running some `react` dev page). I have to specify the port in the url to get there. Tried to put the port into the `hosts` file but it does not work and putting the port in the URL does not work for this.

Comment: You can not change ports using the `hosts` file - see my updated answer. You probably want to do a port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

The listening address on the local instance would be http://auth.site.com:44380/